# What is a word that properly describes a distrust towards anything fast and easy?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

What is a word that describes a distrust/disgust against "fast and easy" or "something for nothing"

thank you all for your time

Comment: My dad's suspicious "if it sounds too good to be true, it probably is" mentality with his cynical "nothing worth having comes easy" attitude was really beginning to get on my nerves.

Comment: Please, show us where you got stuck in your own search, and even more importantly in this case, *how you want to use it*.